# how to use status codes 200, 404, 300 ( how jquery done and fail work internally)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have learnt Ajax by using jQuery. I think jQuery implements using status codes, but don't know much about status codes like 200, 404 and 300.

With jQuery Ajax, its simple as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: customObj
})
.done(function( data ) {
    alert("data saved succesfully");
})
.fail(function( data ) {
    alert( "failed to update data" );
});
```

**Could some one please explain how to use these status codes 200, 404 and 300.**

Comment: @Liam updated the question, Want to know about status codes not ajax

Comment: @Pandu, check out this url http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @pandu, **you've completely changed your question!!** Your original question was a duplicate and has received 4 close votes. If you wanted to ask a different question, which it appears you do, you should of added another question. Now you run the risk of this question getting closed as a duplicate of a question that it is not related too. All in all you've made things very confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to what [@dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21757123/399317) wrote, you can handle specific status codes:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```

or with deferred:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: customObj
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXHR.status == 403) {
        alert( "forbidden" );
    }
});
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "update.php",
    type: "POST",
})
.statusCode({
    401: function() { alert( 'Unauthorized' ); },
    200: function() { alert( 'OK!'); }
});
```

Comment: It's a good addition.

Answer (score 10):

If you take a look at [$.ajax](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.ajax) implementation you will find these lines of code:

```
// Callback for when everything is done
function done(status, nativeStatusText, responses, headers) {

    ...

    // Determine if successful
    isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;

    ...

    // Success/Error
    if (isSuccess) {
        deferred.resolveWith(callbackContext, [success, statusText, jqXHR]);
    } else {
        deferred.rejectWith(callbackContext, [jqXHR, statusText, error]);
    }

    ...
}
```

So the answer is that codes in range 200-300 and 304 are considered successful, and everything else is a failure. Based on that they resolve (`done`, `success` methods will be called) or reject (`fail`) deferred object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which status codes there are, check out:

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP-Statuscode

jQuery will work excatly with those.