# Proper way to test xhr success

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

For years I have used the following expression to test for xmlHttpRequest success in JavaScript:

```
(xhr.status==200)
```

However recently I came across a REST service that returns a different success code (`201`) for some methods. So I plan to change my expression to:

```
(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==201)
```

Does this cover the most usual cases, or am I still missing something? And is there a better way to test for xhr success?

Comment: It's probably "safer" to check that the `status` is `>= 200 && < 300`

Comment: jQuery considers successful codes in range 200-300 and 304 as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21757123/949476

Comment: thx for the comments! Good point about 304.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify that the HTTP request completed successfully (i.e., without network failure or origin-based security issues) by checking that the `readystate` of the request is equal to `xhr.DONE` (i.e., `4`).

Determining whether a network-successful HTTP response represents a "successful" application-level action is partially a per-application question (did the application respond how you expect?), but the `2XX` status codes are grouped in [section 10 of RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) as "Successful" HTTP responses.

Therefore, if you want to test generally for a "success"-type response, test for a status between `200` and `299`, inclusive.

Based on [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742729/proper-way-to-test-xhr-success/26742868#comment42071230_26742729) by [@dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq), [jQuery also includes `304` as a possible "success" response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21757123/949476), because it means that there was no application error and nothing has changed about the resource. Unlike other `3XX` responses, `304` is terminal, so the client has completed the request action and does not need to request another resource in a redirect.